# How do I turn Eclipse Java SE application into J2E application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jakarta-ee

I've application in **Java SE**. Now i would like to turn it into **Java EE** application. I've installed eclipse (maven, tomcat, spring). I am i total beginner to it. if you could show how its is done. It would be a great help.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: i just wanted my java program on web.

Comment: Does this mean that you want to expose functions of your program as a server bases web apllication or just distribute your existing app to run on client side? In the latter case you don't need JEE, you need apple4ts or sth. like webstart.

Comment: The question makes perfect sense if it specifically refers to Eclipse setup.

Comment: @drunix i've an application a banking system (just a simple project) actually and i want it used by other people easily on web.

Comment: @DaveSyer and yes this is my exact question i wanted to ask. Thank you for editing. :)

Comment: The assunming you want to convert a swing based project to a web based one I would suggest you make yourself familar with java web applications, e.g with http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partwebtier.htm#BNADP (You describe yourself as total beginner, so I guess this would be suitable).

Comment: @Drunix hmm ok sure, thank you. I've been reading and learning from youtube and i'll surely look into the link; seems useful for Java EE beginner like me.

Comment: Since you put "spring" in your tags, you might be more interested in the guides [at spring.io](http://spring.io/guides).

Comment: This question is valid IMO and should be re-opened.

Comment: @DaveSyer i've been teaching myself from Arthur Vin in youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0dogNWjqw8) it has maven, spring and other stuffs i don't know about and i've got stuck on 8th part for 5 days and its frustrating :(. Anyway i'll look into that sooner or later. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

To convert Java SE project into Java EE application, you need to change project facets.

1. Right click on the project properties. Select "**Project Facets**", and click "**convert to faceted form…**"
2. Check "**Dynamic Web Module**" and "**Java**", and specify the value.
3. By default, Eclipse will generate all "**web**" related files (like `WEB-INF`, `web.xml`) in a "**WebContent**" folder. If you want change it to another location, Clicks on the "**further configuration available…**" link.

Reference: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-project-to-web-project-in-eclipse/